# Bash Syntax using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to set basic script to check server memory I use "free -m" command in script

but when I used below syntax it does not give required output.

```
available=$($(free-m)|awk '{print $10}')
```

Above syntax gives following error.

```
-bash: total: command not found
```

I also tried by following way.

```
mem=$(free -m)

available=$($t|awk '{print $10}')
```

still same error as follows

```
-bash: total: command not found
```

I also tried following way

```
mem=$(free -m)

available=$(($t|awk '{print $10}'))
```

but it gives error as follows.

```
-bash: 25G: value too great for base (error token is "25G")
```

Therefore kindly suggest

Comment: Divide and conquer. Please test *smaller* sub-parts. Add the results to your question.

Comment: What is your output of `free -m` command what is your expected output?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Also I see at least two "typos", you're claiming the code produce those outputs but they don't (the error messages doesn't match the code). You're essentially lying about what those commands do, which is a big no-no here on SO. Test & Copy paste the results.

Comment: please run free -m command and check...and whatever error I got I just printed here...

anyway I have found the solution for it..just by putting echo in given command i.e.

available=$(echo $(free-m)|awk '{print $10}')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run the `free -m` command on Ubuntu 14.04, it gives output similar to:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           980        917         63          6         17        302
-/+ buffers/cache:        596        383
Swap:         1021          1       1020
$
```

In the question, all that is captured by `$(free -m)`, and the tenth item is the amount of free (available) memory — `63` in the example VM — measured in MiB because of the `-m` option.

As has been explained by other answers, the command line:

```
available=$($(free -m)|awk '{print $10}')
```

is bad because it tries to execute `total` (the first field of the output from `free -m`).

One proposed solution is:

```
available=$(echo $(free -m) | awk '{print $10}')
```

This will work, but is hardly the best solution.  Piping the output of `free -m` to `awk` and printing the appropriate value is more sensible:

```
available=$(free -m | awk 'NR == 2 { print $4 }')
```

Demonstrating the correct output is surprisingly hard; the value from `free -m` depends on what's running.  One way to validate the result is:

```
$ available=$(free -m | awk 'NR == 2 { print $4 } { print >"/dev/stderr" }')
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           980        917         63          6         17        302
-/+ buffers/cache:        596        383
Swap:         1021          1       1020
$ echo available
63
$
```

This copies the input to standard error (`/dev/stderr`), as well as writing the value on standard output, where it is captured and assigned to `available`.  This allows you to check visually that the correct data is printed.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, please explain awk syntax used by you. and I liked your explaination and two different solutions. Thanks

Comment: The main solution (`awk 'NR == 2 { print $4 }'`) prints column 4 of line number 2 of the input (NR is the line number). The checking solution has a second action with an empty pattern, which means the action is executed on each line. The action is `{ print >"/dev/stderr" }`; it means 'print the current line to file `/dev/stderr`, which is a device file that maps to the standard error of the current process (`awk` in this case). So, all the input is copied to standard error; only the 4th column of the 2nd line is printed to standard output and then captured in the shell variable `available`.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution for above question asked by me.

I can get required output (i.e free memory) just by putting echo in above given syntax i.e.

```
available=$(echo $(free -m)|awk '{print $10}')
```